# google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, permissions, google-cloud-storage

Download of a media file by an App Engine service from the Firebase storage.
Assigned permissions (roles):

- Firebase Admin
- Storage Admin

The content of the storage is not public.
The permissions are set via

> ```
> path_service_account = 'xxxxxxx.json'
> os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = path_service_account
> ```

assigned to the service.
The permissions of the bucket are assigned to the appropriate roles. I have also added the service as a member.

The file is to be temporarily stored in tmp/ for further processing.
At

> input_blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

follows:

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET
> https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/uploaded_videos/o/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4?alt=media:
> ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of',
> <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)

resp.

> File
> "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py",
> line 96, in require_status_code *status_codes
> google.resumable_media.common.InvalidResponse: ('Request failed with
> status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>,
> <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)

EDIT:
Additional information after clicking the file link in the returned message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unknown output format: media:",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Unknown output format: media:",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalidAltValue",
        "locationType": "parameter",
        "location": "alt"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The funny thing is that in google source code
https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html
you can see that '?alt: media' is added

> _DOWNLOAD_URL_TEMPLATE = u"{hostname}/download/storage/v1{path}?alt=media"

But the problem is the **colon** at the end of the download file name:
https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/uploaded_videos/o/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4?alt=media:

Any idea how to bypass this?

Comment: Looking at the link from the error `https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/uploaded_videos/o/.mp4?` - are you sure that you provided proper object name for `input_blob`? he seems to search for `.mp4` name...

Comment: @vitooh yes, I'm sure, I deleted the name in my post for security reason.

Comment: Can you add more details how to replicate the issue?